# Why does the List Selection Listener interrupt my method?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, indexoutofboundsexception, listselectionlistener

I'm using NetBeans and it's GUI Builder. 
My problem is that I apparently can not use the List Selection Listener properly.

I got two methods. The first one just should get the index of the selected item of the JList and use that to retrieve data out of an ArrayList to put that in various fields. (int index is declared globally)

```
private void mitarbeiterAnzeigeValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                                
    if(evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) {        //I didn't put the "!" here because then this method would do nothing.
        JList jl = (JList) evt.getSource();
        index = jl.getSelectedIndex();
        nameTextField2.setText(Arbeitsplan.mitarbeiterListe.get(index).gibNamen());
        beschäftigungsartBox2.setSelectedItem(Arbeitsplan.mitarbeiterListe.get(index).gibBeschäftigungsart());
        wochenstundenTextField2.setValue(Arbeitsplan.mitarbeiterListe.get(index).gibWochenstunden());
    }
}
```

Arbeitsplan is my main class and mitarbeiterListe the ArrayList in there.

First of, why do I have to not put the "!" in front of the "getValueIsAdjusting()"?

The second method should delete entries out of the JList as well as out of the ArrayList.
Moreover is should clear the TextFields.

```
private void mitarbeiterLöschenButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
    Arbeitsplan.mitarbeiterListe.remove(index);
    mitarbeiterListModel.remove(index);        
    mitarbeiterAnzeige.remove(index);
    mitarbeiterAnzeige.setModel(mitarbeiterListModel);

    nameTextField2.setText("");
    beschäftigungsartBox2.setSelectedIndex(0);
    wochenstundenTextField2.setValue("");              
}
```

After "mitarbeiterAnzeige.remove(index);" the thread changes to the first method again and nothing works in the end. I get an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" message.

Why does the Listener react within my second method?
Or more general, what are my mistakes?

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 0):

Adding "if (index >= 0)" before something in the list model (not in the list itself) is changed made it!